# Unable to read Registry value using PowerShell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, registry

I am not able to read specific registry values using PowerShell in C#. Here is the code:

Calling function:

```
    public static string UserDisplayName()
    {
        // PowerShell Command: (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\1').LoggedOnDisplayName
        return GetPowerShellOutputString(@"(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\1').LoggedOnDisplayName");
    }
```

Function definition:

```
    private static string GetPowerShellOutputString(string PsCmd)
    {
        try
        {
            string PsOut = string.Empty;
            Debug.Write("PsCmd: " + PsCmd + "; ");
            Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            rs.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = rs.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd);
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            rs.Close();

            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                if (obj != null) PsOut += obj.ToString() + ", ";

            PsOut = (PsOut == string.Empty) ? strUnavailableString : PsOut.TrimEnd(',', ' ');
            Debug.WriteLine("PsOut: " + PsOut);
            return PsOut;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("! " + ex.Message + ex.InnerException + "\n");
            return strUnavailableString;
        }
    }
```

However, the same Function definition is working perfectly if I am trying to read any other registry value e.g.:

```
    public static string UserOUPath()
    {
        try
        {
            if (UserDomain() == SystemInformation.ComputerName) return strUnavailableString; // Non-domain account

            //For consistant performance, grab OU from registry instead of AD.
            string userSID = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString();
            string ouPath = @"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\" + userSID;
            string ou = GetPowerShellOutputString("(Get-ItemProperty -Path '" + ouPath + "').'Distinguished-Name'");

            ou = ou.Remove(0, ou.IndexOf(",", 0) + 1); // Drop leading CN stuff
            ou = ou.Remove(ou.IndexOf(",DC=", 0), ou.Length - ou.IndexOf(",DC=", 0)); // Drop trailing DC stuff
            ou = ou.Replace(",OU=", "/");
            ou = ou.Replace("OU=", "/");
            ou = FlipOU(ou);

            if (ou == null) throw new NullReferenceException();

            return ou;
        }
        catch
        {
            return strUnavailableString;
        }
    }
```

For the first call (UserDisplayName()) when I did Debug mode, the ***results*** object is returning ***null***. However if I run the same PowerShell Command in PowerShell window it is giving the value.

I am stumbled upon this as I am not able to get why and what is happening?

Comment: *"read specific registry values using PowerShell in C#"* You what? Why? Can't you read registry values using C# methods?

Comment: I see this time after time here. If you're developing in c#, USE c# and it's .net classes. PowerShell is slow and complicated and it uses the same .Net classes that you could access directly in c# much easier and faster.

Comment: Why would you ever do this!? You're passing a *PowerShell* script into *C#* which *already has* much better functionality for reading registry values! You're over-complicating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things. First I agree with all the comments about just using the Microsoft.Win32.Registry* classes directly in C#.  However to answer your question about doing this from PowerShell, I believe what you are running into a registry virtualization issue.  If your C# project is AnyCPU and run under Visual Studio it is likely running 32-bit and that registry path will be virtualized to the SysWow64 registry node.  So your reg path won't exist.  That can be fixed by making the exe compile as x64. Another option is to use the .NET Registry.OpenBaseKey() method will allows you to specify which reg hive you want to view (32-bit or 64-bit).

Second, you can simplify your code by using the PowerShell class e.g.:

```
 var ps = PowerShell.Create();
 ps.AddScript(PsCmd);
 var results = ps.Invoke();
 foreach (PSObject obj in results)
     if (obj != null) PsOut += obj.ToString() + ", ";
```

Third, with the PowerShell class, after the Invoke() call, check the Error stream for errors like so:

```
 foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error)
     Console.Error.WriteLine(error);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I just changed the Platform target to x64 (from x86) and it is working now. Though there are classes available to read the value. I was just curious to know the reason for this random behavior.
Now I can have a good sleep tonight :-)